# Pivot table Data Range selection using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Im trying to work on a data in a pivot table by selecting it first but except for the grand Totals.
I still want the grand totals to be displayed. when I write:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").DataBodyRange.select
```

I get this:
[image]

(all the data including the grand totals is selected)

but I want it to be like this:
[image]

How can I ignore the grand totals when selecting the data?

Comment: Use the `Resize` and `Offset` methods on the `DataBodyRange` object.

Answer (score 1):

With `Resize` you can change the size of selected range:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).DataBodyRange
rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, rng.Columns.Count - 1).Select
```

`rng.Rows.Count - 1` is responsible for diminishing number of rows by 1. I had to squeeze the columns by 1 to exclude both grand totals out of the selection.

You can do it in one shot, if you do not like `Dim`:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).DataBodyRange.Resize(ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).DataBodyRange.Rows.Count - 1, ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).DataBodyRange.Columns.Count-1).Select
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!